# Angular Material Dialog, cant update data dynamically

Tags: angular, angular-material

```js
import { CdkDragEnd, CdkDragStart } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, OnInit, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { StackPalletsComponent } from '../modals/stack-pallets/stack-pallets.component';
import { Pallet } from '../models/pallet';
import { MainServiceService } from '../services/main-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-warehouse-stack',
  templateUrl: './warehouse-stack.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./warehouse-stack.component.css']
})
export class WarehouseStackComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges{

  @Input() warehouseStackID = null;
  @Input() name = null;
  @Input() position = null;
  @Input() pallets: Pallet[] = null;

  private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<StackPalletsComponent>;
  
  constructor(public mainService:MainServiceService,public dialog:MatDialog) { }
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    console.log(this.dialogRef)
    if (this.dialogRef && this.dialogRef.componentInstance) {
        this.dialogRef.componentInstance.data = {
                      warehouseID: this.warehouseID,
                      pallets: this.pallets
                  }
}
  }


  public dragging:boolean;

  
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }


  updatePosition(e: CdkDragEnd) {
    this.mainService.updateStackPosition(this.warehouseStackID, e.source.getFreeDragPosition().x, e.source.getFreeDragPosition().y)
  }

  public handleDragStart(event: CdkDragStart): void {
    this.dragging = true;
  }

  handleClick(event: MouseEvent): void {
    if (this.dragging) {
      this.dragging = false;
      return
    } 
    this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(StackPalletsComponent, {
      data: {
        warehouseStackID: this.warehouseStackID,
        pallets: this.pallets
      }
    });
    console.log(this.dialogRef)
  }
}
```

So, i have pallets, a List coming from input of parent component, and i need to pass it into dialog every time it changes, using component instance. The problem is that if i console log it in OnChanges(), it says that this object is undefined for some reasons, despite i assigned it in my handleClick function.

**StackPalletsComponent.html**

```
<div class="pallets">
    <app-pallet *ngFor="let pallet of this.data.pallets" [position]="{x:pallet.positionX, y:pallet.positionY}" [pallet]="pallet"></app-pallet>
    <div class="cubeRow">
        <div class="cube"></div>
        <div class="cube"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cubeRow">
        <div class="cube"></div>
        <div class="cube"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cubeRow">
        <div class="cube"></div>
        <div class="cube"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <button class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light red" style="margin-top: 5px;" (click)="showCreationModal()"><i class="material-icons">add</i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**StackPalletsComponent.ts**

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { Pallet } from 'src/app/models/pallet';
import { MainServiceService } from 'src/app/services/main-service.service';
import { CreatePalletComponent } from '../create-pallet/create-pallet.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-stack-pallets',
  templateUrl: './stack-pallets.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./stack-pallets.component.css']
})
export class StackPalletsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public mainService:MainServiceService, public dialogRef:MatDialogRef<StackPalletsComponent>, public dialog:MatDialog,@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: {warehouseStackID: number, pallets: Pallet[]}) { }

  

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }

  showCreationModal() {
    this.dialog.open(CreatePalletComponent, {
      data: {
        isStackPallet: true,
        warehouseStackID: this.data.warehouseStackID
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: to understand more you change the data then open the dialog or you change it while opening it also can you put the code of "StackPalletsComponent" or you can put example using https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: @MohamedEnab Im looping through pallets, and i want them to render instantly after adding. I know that i need to use componentInstance.data for that, but for some reason, even if i open dialog, dialogRef remains undefined.

Comment: @MohamedEnab I also noticed a few minutes ago, that any variable assigned in handleClick() doesn't assign. I created a boolean variable B equal to false, changed it using this.B = true, and console.log(B) inside onChange(), it remains false for some reason.